# custom theme: add template file in default.xml

Tags: error, magento2.2, exception, custom-theme, custom-template

here my default.xml

```
 <body>       
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
       <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customeline" template="Magento_Theme::customeline.phtml"/>
   </referenceContainer>
   <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/mytheme-logo-snake.png</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">80</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">80</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

here my phtml file

```
<div class="block" style="float: left;">
<?php echo __('this is custom theme'); ?>
</div>
```

/frontend/Bigstore/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

/frontend/BIgstore/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/customline.phtml

error:-

> exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Theme::customeline.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'customline'

Answer (score 1):

**Put your file in below path :**

> /frontend/BIgstore/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/customline.phtml

**Change in your default.xml**

> /frontend/Bigstore/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customeline" template="Magento_Theme::html/customeline.phtml"/>            
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: have you run php bin/magento set:up command after adding file ?

Comment: i have tried this one

Comment: I have updated xml code.

Comment: i created html and moved phtml into folder and change the file name.

Comment: If above solution works for you please vote and accept so another will use same :)

Comment: tell me how to add image in phtml file

Comment: added new comment

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the code of `default.xml`.
You specify template file name "`customeline.phtml`" and you create file "`customline.phtml`".
Change file name in your code like this.

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
       <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customeline" template="Magento_Theme::customline.phtml"/>
   </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Image in PHTML file:**

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/demo.png'); ?>"/>
```

**Image in Static Block or CMS page:**

```
<img src="{{view url="images/demo.jpg"}}"/>
```

Comment: @Dipak Solanki is any solution work for you don't forgot to vote up accept answer.